# build dynamic EL ExpressionString

Tags: jsf-2, el

I build a dynamic datatable with jsf. 
I get columndescriptions from a bean and use `c:forEach` to create the table.
In the columndescription the name of the property which should be displayed is stored. 
I use `h:outputText value="#{record[cd.property]}"/>` to display the value in the table.

Now I have columns which refer to a sub-entity, so the EL expression would be something like this:

```
    record.property.property2.property3 or record[property].property2.propert3
```

Is it possible to create an EL Expression to such an sub-Entity or are there other possibilities to evaluate the Value for the columns?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Severin

**Edit** further explanation:

I store an String like "property.property2.property3" in a bean an would like to use it as EL-Expression. So i can dynamicaly create the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i maybe didn't explained it enought (sorry). I would like to create the EL-Expression at runtime. So i would like to get the String "record.property.property2.property3" from the bean, and use it as EL-Epression. (I updated the question)

Comment: Any new informations on this? I have a search component for `Foo`. Now i need the same for `BarHasFoo` and basically i must copy whole component and replace all `property` with `foo.property`. Rest of the component and logic is identical.

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter and send the path as attribute to converter and return the value as string:

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
    String path = (String) arg1.getAttributes().get("path");
    if (path != null) {
        try {
            return BeanUtils.getProperty(arg2, path);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LoggingUtil.logMessage(ex, "converter failed for path = " + path + " for object = " + arg2.getClass());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```